# How to annotate a response type ImmutableMap for swagger

Tags: spring, swagger, immutability, springfox

How do you document a response that is an `ImmutableMap`?
The response is a singleton immutablemap, and the key of the map is fixed.

This is the body of the method.

```
return ImmutableMap.of("key_name", function_returning_string());
```

The result type of the method is `Map<String, String>`.

With no annotation for response, the output on swagger UI is merely showing this:

```
{}
```

When using ReDoc to render the API, the result is as follows:

[image]

I'd like to have this "property name" field rendered as the value of the key used in the single immutable map.

Help!